# Is this piecewise function continuous in topology generated by intervals $[a, b)$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $ \tau_S$ be the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $ \tau_H$ be a topology generated by intervals $[a, b)$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $f(x)=  \begin{cases} 0 & x< 0 \\x & x\geq 0 \end{cases}$.

We know $f$ is continuous as $f:(\mathbb{R},\tau_S) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\tau_S)$, but is it continuous as $f:(\mathbb{R},\tau_S) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\tau_H)$?

My initial thought was that the preimage of an open set  [,)  in the second topology is not an open set in the standard topology, so the function is not continuous, is this true?

Comment: Well what have you tried? How does the preimage of an open set look under that second map?

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:piecewise-continuity]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I mistakingly thought to add it since I have a piecewise-defined function, I will remove it

Comment: @FedePoncio My initial thought was that the preimage of an open set $[a,b)$ in the second topology is not an open set in the standard topology, so the function is not continuous

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question, by adding that thought of yours to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, effectively. Take the set $[1,2) \in \tau_H$ as a counterexample. It's preimage is $[1,2)\subset\mathbb{R}$, which is not an open set in the standard topology. So the map cannot be continuous.

It seems that you had thought about all of this yourself. I suggest that next time you add all of your thoughts in the body of the question directly. You really didn't need an answer, but a confirmation of what you had already tried.